# Improving the convergence speed in a Leibniz series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have read the proof for the Leibniz criterion. Underneath there was a remark that I did not understand it says that if we have a Leibniz series than one can obtain $s$ sometimes faster by calculating the (arithmetic) mean value and with index shift.

With Leibniz series I mean that $(a_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing zero-convergent sequence. And the Leibniz  series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges. Let $s$ be the value it converges to

My Question why

$\frac 1 2a_0+\frac 1 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n-a_{n+1})$

also converges to $s$?

And if

$|s-\sum_{n=0}^k(-1)^na_n|\leq a_{k+1}$

Why is

$|s-\big(\frac 1 2a_0+\frac 1 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n-a_{n+1})\big)|\leq a_{k+1} a_{k+2}$

Thanks for helping

What I have thought so far is that the if we have

$\frac 1 2a_0+\frac 1 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n-a_{n+1})$

then the Right Hand side cannot converge to $s$ it must somehow compensate the influence of the Always constant $a_0/2$ in a way that it converges to $s$. Maybe one can do someting with the distributive law but I am not sure if I am allowed to use it.

In particular if $L=\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1}$

then also

$L=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}-\frac{1}{4\cdot 5}+ …\big)$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: To see what is going on, take a look at the simpler example of taking the sum from $n=0$ to $n=3$: $\frac12a_0+\frac12(a_0-a_1)-\frac12(a_1-a_2)+\frac12(a_2-a_3)-\frac12(a_3-a_4)=a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\frac12a_4$

Comment: I believe that $a_n=10^{-n}$ shows that the proposition about the error of the accelerated series doesn't hold; that is, $|s-\big(\frac 1 2a_0+\frac 1 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_n-a_{n+1})\big)|\leq a_{k+1} a_{k+2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing on my comment:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12a_0+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(a_k-a_{k+1})
&=\frac12a_0+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_k-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_{k+1}\\
&=\frac12a_0+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_k-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}a_k\\
&=\frac12a_0+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_k+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^ka_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_k+\frac12(-1)^{n+1}\,a_{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
If you are uncertain what you can use in an infinite sum, apply rules to a finite sum and then take the limit.